# Issue in scipy.minimize with method SLSQP

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I have some trouble with the SLSQP method. I hope it's not something stupid. So, the minimal code is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as scopt

def loss(x,r):
        return -np.dot(x,r)

def opt(r):
    def cons(x):
        return sum(x)

    cons = [{'type': 'eq', 'fun': cons}]

    x_opt = scopt.minimize(loss, [0., 0.], method='SLSQP', constraints=cons, args = (r,))

    return x_opt
```

For context, think of it as a minimization of loss coming from a set of investment volumes x, given some returns r. The only constraint is that there is no creation of money, so the sum of the investments should be 0.

So, if I set r = [0., 0.1], everything is fine, the function returns an error because there is no minimum -- you can set x[0] to minus infinity and x[1] to plus infinity to maximize your profit. But if I set instead r = [0., 0.001], then there is no error and the function returns always the initial value ([0., 0.] here).

It seems like a bug coming from a rounding error, but I am surprised, because this method is widely used... Do I miss something?

I am using python3 and scipy 0.14.

EDIT:
I am sure this is bug now, because I have tried to solve this optimization problem with the cvxopt module, which returns the right solution. I have reported the bug and I am waiting a confirmation from the scipy guys before answering this question. If that's not the proper way of doing it, somebody tells me, I am new on SO.

Comment: I am also having issues with this method on python 3. I have a program that runs perfectly on python 2, but produces many `nan` values on python 3. I am not sure why there is any difference. Have you made any progress on this?

Comment: Hi, apparently there is a issue in the tolerance criteria in the original fortran code, I have to take a look at this when I'll have a moment. Since my problem should be independent of the version of python (even though I have not tested), yours is probably a different issue.